# Javascript If statement, looking through an specific array using - Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to scan for specific array value using  if statement I've  tried the code bellow but it doest work. array value =
["Birth Certificate","Completion Certificate","Good Moral","Form 138","TOR (Form 137)","Diploma"]

```
    @if( in_array($request->requirements) == "Good Moral"){

    $( "#goodmoral" ).prop( "checked", true );

    }
    @endif
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in_array function to check for `"Good Moral"` in your array like this:

```
@if( in_array("Good Moral", $request->requirements))
    $( "#goodmoral" ).prop( "checked", true );
@endif
```

`in_array()` takes an argument that is used as the search needle and an array in which to search for.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Comment: it gives me this error dear:< = Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, string given

Comment: That means that $request->requirements is not an array... @Angel
Am i correct, that this should be the array described in the question?